# Parsing C# in Java Application

Tags: c#, java, parsing

I'm looking to parse a C# code base within a Java app.  I need to know where classes, methods, members, etc are defined (both filename and line number).  What are the best tools/libraries to do this.

It looks like the Doxygen executable could be invoked and then its output XML files could be read.

Are there any other solutions out there?

I'm doing this in Java because its for a specialized application.

Comment: Doesn't visual studio already give you this? Why are you trying to do it with Java?

Comment: Do you have a question about *programming* other than  asking *Are there any other solutions out there?*

Comment: WTF?  This is about programming.  Did you want some abstract computer science problem or something?

Comment: @ademartini Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I think this question could be useful to others if discussed.  Whats with the big fear of "opinions!!!" :p

Comment: @ademartini, say you get a list of libraries. What happens in 3 years when a reader looks for this question, and finds outdated links and solutions?

Comment: I don't see that as being tightly coupled with the concept of an opinion. This is fun!

Comment: On Hold?  Its the tyranny of the majority :P    At least I got my answer.

Comment: @gunr: lets say somebody offers you a piece of code compiled by V17.92.36 of your current compiler.  Where's the proof that in 3 years that code will still compile and work?  I find the "answer gets stale" argument a bit disingenuous; this is high-tech, where all answers are stale after a couple of years.   Tools aren't different.

Comment: On the subject of opinions, I would bet that a pretty large percentage of what is said on this site is an opinion.  You know what they say, opinions are like...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://antlr3.org/grammar/list.html), there **is** a [CSharp Grammer](https://github.com/ChristianWulf/CSharpGrammar) for ANTLR.  I don't know how complete it is, but it includes a preprocessor, parser and lexer.

Comment: Link only answer. And product recommendation.

Comment: Thanks so much Elliot, this was a useful link.  I think it may be better than just invoking Doxygen from the command-line.